# Why my db data lost after docker restart?

Tags: sql-server, docker-compose

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    sqldata:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
        environment:
            - SA_PASSWORD=YourStrong@Passw0rd
            - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
        ports:
            - "1433:1433"
        volumes:
            - ./docker/mssql:/var/opt/mssql
```

Each time when I did `docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d` all databases that I created are deleted.

How to prevent this deleting after each docker restart?

Comment: [`docker-compose down`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) Appears to **remove** the container, not stop it. I *assume* you want [`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) and [`docker start`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/) (or perhaps [`docker restart`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/restart/)).

Comment: @Larnu I think that you are right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use docker stop and docker start instead of docker-compose down.